# Saving many to many in nestjs

Tags: crud, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity Resource with a many to many relationship with location

```js
@Entity("resource")
export class Resource extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 500, nullable: true })
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(
    type => Location,
    location => location.resources,
    { cascade: true }
  )
  @JoinTable({
    name: "resource_location",
  })
  locations: Location[];
}
```

```js
@Entity("location")
export class Location extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 500, nullable: true })
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(
    type => Resource,
    resource => resource.locations
  )
  resources: Resource[];

}
```

And I'm using nestjs crud plugin for the controller

```js
@Crud({
  model: {
    type: Resource
  }
})
@Controller("resource")
export class ResourceController {
  constructor(public service: ResourceService) {}
}
```

I want to be able to pass and object like this and it will create all the relationship records

```
POST /resource
{
  name: 'resourceName',
  locations: [1,2] // provided these locations are in the locations table
}
```

this format seams to be a standard in other frameworks such as django but doesn't work out of the box in nest with crud/typeorm. Also trying to implement the functionality seams a bit difficult too if I were to try to override the method like this:

```js
export class ResourceController {
  constructor(
    public service: ResourceService,
    private readonly locationService: LocationService
  ) {}

  get base(): CrudController<Resource> {
    return this;
  }

  @Override("createOneBase")
  async createOne(
    @ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest,
    @ParsedBody() dto: Resource
  ) {
    let locations;
    if (dto.locations) {
      locations = dto.locations.map(
        async v => await this.locationService.findOne(v)
      );
    }
    dto.locations = locations;

    return this.base.createOneBase(req, dto);
  }
}
```

I just end up getting the error:

```
Nest] 18527   - 02/18/2020, 4:31:50 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined +1602ms
TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
    at Object.encrypt (/Users/natedeazy/projects/MedOneScheduling/scheduling-backend/node_modules/typeorm-encrypted/lib/transformers/index.js:14:83)
    at AutoEncryptSubscriber.beforeInsert (/Users/natedeazy/projects/MedOneScheduling/scheduling-backend/node_modules/typeorm-encrypted/lib/subscribers/AutoEncryptSubscriber.js:18:24)
    at /Users/natedeazy/projects/MedOneScheduling/scheduling-backend/node_modules/typeorm/subscriber/Broadcaster.js:39:54
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Broadcaster.broadcastBeforeInsertEvent (/Users/natedeazy/projects/MedOneScheduling/scheduling-backend/node_modules/typeorm/subscriber/Broadcaster.js:37:53)
    at /Users/natedeazy/projects/MedOneScheduling/scheduling-backend/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectExecutor.js:162:99
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SubjectExecutor.broadcastBeforeEventsForAll (/Users/natedeazy/projects/MedOneScheduling/scheduling-backend/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectExecutor.js:162:33)
    at SubjectExecutor.<anonymous> (/Users/natedeazy/projects/MedOneScheduling/scheduling-backend/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectExecutor.js:68:50)
    at step (/Users/natedeazy/projects/MedOneScheduling/scheduling-backend/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:136:27)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how to save data in express js. You can compare syntax with nestjs; it's not different

```
 async CreateNewUser(data: any): Promise<User | any> {
        try {
          if (data) {
            if (data.password) {
              data.password = await argon2.hash(data.password);
            }
          }
          console.log("data", data)
          let entity = await this.userRepository.create(data);
          console.log("entity", entity)
          // let entity2 = { ...entity, company: [{ id: data.entreprise }], roles: data.role }
          let entity2 = { ...entity, company: data.company, roles: data.selectedRoles }
    
          console.log("entityyyyyyyyyyyyy2", entity2)
          const user = await this.userRepository.save(entity2);
          console.log('data.user', data.user);
          this.trackingService.create(data.user);
          //todo we need to serialize the user
          // return only what we need like username , email, ...etc not password!!!!
          return { success: true, user: SanitizeUser(user) };
        } catch (e) {
          //  code == 23505 means duplication key
          if (parseInt(e.code) === 23505) {
            console.log('error : ', e.detail);
            return {
              success: false,
              message: USER_ERROR_MESSAGES.USER_IS_FOUND,
            };
          } else {
            return {
              success: false,
            };
          }
        }
      }
```